# Detect in simulink if the current and past 4 values are same or not

Tags: simulink

I am interested in designing a simulink block which detects if the past 4 and the current input values are same or not. How to do it using the delay blocks and relational operators since the relational operators take only two inputs at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you 4 [Unit Delay](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/unitdelay.html) blocks in succession, you will get the previous 4 values by looking at the output of each block. You didn't say whether you were using a fixed-step or variable-step solver. Normally, you should be using a fixed-step solver for this type of operation.

With regards to the equality test, I would recommend comparing the absolute value of the difference between the 2 numbers to a small threshold rather than doing a pure equality test, especially if your signals are of the `double` data type. The blocks you need for that are:

- [Compare to Constant](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/comparetoconstant.html)
- [Subtract](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/subtract.html)
- [Abs](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/abs.html)